# How to get the bad records from a partially loaded parquet file in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

trying to get the bad records of a partially loaded parquet file  using validation_mode.

used the following **copy statement in snowpipe to load data into table**.

```
copy into table from @extg_stage/folder

pattern='.*snappy.parquet' 

file_format=(format_name='parquet_file_format') 

match_by_column_name=case_insensitive;
```

and to **get bad records from a file**.

```
copy into table_name from @extg_stage/test.snappy.parquet
file_format=(format_name='parquet_file_format')
validation_mode=return_all_errors;
```

got the error 1:
**PARQUET file format can produce one and only one column of type vatiant,object or array. Load data into separate columns using the MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME copy option or copy with transformation**

and when used the match_by_column_name parameter in the copy statement

```
copy into table_name from @extg_stage/test.snappy.parquet
file_format=(format_name='parquet_file_format')
match_by_column_name=case_insesitive
validation_mode=return_all_errors;
```

got the error 2:
**MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME cannot be used with the VALIDATION_MODE beacsuse VALIDATION_MODE does not support COPY with transform**

and snowflake document says validation_mode doesn't support along with match_by_column_name parameter.

Comment: Hi - the error message suggests that your COPY statement is failing as a whole, rather than that it’s loading some rows and failing others. If your target table contains more than a single column (of type variant) then you need to map fields in the source to columns in your target - as shown in this example: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/script-data-load-transform-parquet#step-4-copy-data-into-the-target-table

Comment: Have you tried the VALIDATE table function?

Comment: @NickW the loading is done through snowpipe and the VALIDATE function requires query_id, is it possible to use VALIDATE function in this scenario?

Comment: Hi - it’s helpful when you ask a question to include all the relevant information, such as the fact that you are using Snowpipe. Anyway, try the COPY_HISTORY table function

Comment: @NickW the COPY_HISTORY table function gives the first error in the file. i think it does not give the total bad records in a file.